# How to disable dates in jDatePicker Java

Tags: java, datepicker

This is probably very easy but I could not find a solution.

I have two jDatePickers generated using the code below (using jdatepicker 1.3.4 jar).

```
    UtilDateModel model = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put( "text.today", "Today" );
    p.put( "text.month", "Month" );
    p.put( "text.year", "Year" );
    JDatePanelImpl datePanel = new JDatePanelImpl( model, p );
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker1 = new JDatePickerImpl( datePanel, new DateComponentFormatter() );

    UtilDateModel model2 = new UtilDateModel();
    Properties p2 = new Properties();
    p2.put( "text.today", "Today" );
    p2.put( "text.month", "Month" );
    p2.put( "text.year", "Year" );
    JDatePanelImpl datePanelTo = new JDatePanelImpl( model2, p2 );
    JDatePickerImpl datePicker2 = new JDatePickerImpl( datePanelTo, new DateComponentFormatter() );

    datePicker1.addPropertyChangeListener( new PropertyChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange( PropertyChangeEvent arg0 )
        {
            //code to disable
        }
    } );
```

I want to disable the dates in datepicker2 so that it cannot select dates before the selected date in datepicker1. What should go into the event listener?

Answer (score 0):

you can check out this..

```
   datePicker2.getComponent(1).setEnabled(false);
```